Minimum of $f(x,y) =\ e^{x(1-da)-\ y(1-a)}+e^{-x(1+da)+y(1+a)}$ where $0<a<\frac{1}{d}$ and $d>1$.
I need to find the minimum of
$$f(x,y) = e^{x(1-da)- y(1-a)}+e^{-x(1+da)+y(1+a)}=e^{x-y - a(dx-y)}+e^{-(x- y)
-a(dx-y)}\tag{1}$$ where $0<a<\frac{1}{d}$ and $d>1$.
Solving $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = 0$, I get
$$2x-2y = \ln \frac{1+da}{1-da}\tag{2}$$
Solving $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = 0$, I get
$$2x-2y = \ln \frac{1+a}{1-a}\tag{3}$$
I found the result strange, as I can not retrieve $x$ and $y$. Can you please someone cast some light on my problem?

Perhaps the minimum is not attained.

Let $y=x.$ Then
$$x(1-da)-y(1-a)=a(1-d)x\\ -x(1+da)+y(1+a)=a(1-d)x$$ As $d>1$ and $a>0$ we get $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x,x)=0.$

Thank you for the answer.

Is it possible to use the $x-y$ in (2) or/and (3) in (1) ?

The conditions $(2)$ and $(3)$ cannot be satisfied simultaneously as $(1+da)/(1-da)>(1+a)/(1-a).$ This means there are no stationary points.  Thus the function does not admit local extrema.
